# Solving a differential equation with Reduction of order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi so I have this question here:

> Find the general solution to the equation for $y=y(x)$,
>   . $$y''+4y'+4y=e^{-2x}\sec^2(x)$$
>   by using reduction of order.

The problem is that, for reduction of order, I need one of the solutions. The only hint that is given is

*What would be a good choice for a solution to the homogeneous equation?*

I already have the homogeneous equation solved which is $y_{h}(x)=c_1e^{-2x}+c_2xe^{-2x}$.

I COULD use variation of parameters to get the particular solution but the questions asks me to use reduction of order.

How am I just supposed to "guess" one of the solutions? Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to end up with $e^{-2x}\sec^2x$ and $\sec^2x$ is the derivative of $\tan x$ and $\tan x$ is the derivative of $\ln|\sec x|$ the first thing I would try for a particular solution is $y_p=e^{-2x}\ln|\sec x|$.

Reduction of order would only be needed to find the second homogeneous solution given the solution $e^{-2x}$.

Hint: It works. Check it.